# Authorize anonymous API endpoint from azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I have a `[Allow Anonymous]`.net core api endpoint which will execute some code. I need this endpoint to be hit every 5 hours, for this, i made a Logic App Run on Azure that is calling my endpoint. How can i secure this endpoint in order to allow the requests only from Azure ? I don't want somebody to call my endpoint 1000 times / minute. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you app service look for **Netwoking** on the left. Click on **Configue Access Restictions**

[image]

In the following dialog you can configure which IP Addresses are allowed or denied.
In my sample i only allowed traffic coming from IP 43.200.34.2

[image]

Comment: thank you a lot but i think the idea is to make restrictions on my API because the API will receive the request not the Azure

Comment: Anyway, i don't know how to debug a HTTP request which is comming from Azure on my localhost, because i can't put localhost on the URL section of the HTTP

Comment: well. then ask the right question. this answer solved your initial problem you asked for. Open a new question.

Comment: How can i secure this endpoint in order to allow the requests ONLY from Azure ? is the question :)

Comment: you will need to add the list of azure IP ranges :-) See: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653 (Azure has a lot of IP Ranges)

Comment: I would add a HEADER value in the request object. Something like a *secret*. Then validate that header in you app service. people would also be able to hit your API but nothing will happen if they do not pass the correc header.